# What is the proper way to add an attribute to a base class in a Python library and have it inherited?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am trying to extend a Python library to add functionality I desire.  The library provides a number of HTML form objects (such as `Textbox`, `Dropdown`, `Checkbox`, etc.), all derived from an `Input` object.  I want to add an additional attribute to all of these derived objects.  What is the proper way of proceeding?

I can:

1. Modify the original source code for the `Input` class, adding the attribute I want.
2. Create a new class that inherits `Input` and adds my attribute, and then create a bunch of new classes that inherit `Textbox`, `Dropdown`, and my new `Input` class.
3. Create new classes for `Textbox`, `Dropdown`, etc. with the attribute.

Solution 1 is the easiest and simplest, but is inherently wrong, whereas the other two seem like much more work and code-repetition than this task should call for.

Is there a solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 4th solution is monkey patching and **might** be a good idea. Before you try this, make sure this won't break anything now or in the future:

```
def additional_method(self, arg):
    print("hello", arg)

Input.additional_method = additional_method
```

or for short stuff:

```
Input.additional_method = lambda self, arg: do_something(arg)
```

now all existing and future `Input` instances (and therefore instances of all `Input` subclasses) have an `additional_method` attached to them.

This works also for any future subclasses of `Input` that might not even exist yet, or you might not be aware of, at the time of adding the method, so is therefore better (i.e. more generic) than creating an alternative inheritance hierarchy, which you'll have to then maintain and keep in sync with upstream changes.

**NOTE:** before you downvote just because it contains the phrase "monkey patching", consider that monkey patching doesn't have to be dangerous/fragile, and is a first class (as in "respected") feature in many languages.

Comment: I like this solution compared to a mixin, but can it be applied in cases where I want the derived classes to be able to take a new parameter from `**kwargs` and set it as an attribute? Can `__init__()` be monkey patched?

Comment: Yes to both questions: 1) methods introduced using monkey patching can do all the same things that "normal" methods can and 2) `__init__` is really just a method; but monkey-patching `__init__` already begins to sound like a bad idea under most circumstances :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a mixin (multiple inheritance). It's a class that just contains your extra attribute, and add this class to the parent class of a subclass of `Textbox, Dropdown, Checkbox...` like this:

```
from ... import TextBox

class Mixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_attribude = ...

class TextBox_with_new_attribute(Mixin, TextBox):
    pass
```

But, it depends tightly on your goals...

Edit: base on @Veedrac comment, in case of third party library.

Comment: In this solution, the `...` under `class TextBox(Mixin, Input):` would be copy-and-pasted from the library's `TextBox()`?

Comment: It could just be `pass`, dude, if the class was defined `class TextBox(Mixin, them.TextBox)`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of classes you could dynamically apply a mixin:

```
for cls in list_of_classes_to_patch:
    patched = type(cls.__name__, (my_mixin, cls), {})
    setattr(place_to_export, cls.__name__, patched)
```

`place_to_export` can be defined as `import this_module as place_to_export`.